Best phase unwrapping algorithm in single precision
I’m wondering what is the best algorithm for unwrapping phase of a signal whose data type is single (float) that posess the least sensitivity to roundoff error. In my application I need to compute the instantaneous frequency from the unwrapped phase. For example, just for the sake of illustration, lets consider a simple sinusoid at 200 Hz that is sampled at a rate 2000 Hz. I used the code below to compute the instantaneous unwrapped phase
fs = 2000; % sample rate
f0 = 200; % carrier frequency
T = 32; % duration, the higher T, the more roundoff noise is acrrued
t = (single(0):1/fs:T)';
x = cos(*pi*f0*t);

xhilb = hilbert(x);
xangl = angle(xhilb);
puwrp = unwrap(xangl);

And then from puwrp, the instantaneous frequency is computed as below
finst = (fs/(2*pi))*diff(puwrp);

The $l_\infty$ of the error f0-finst is on the order of 40 Hz.
norm(f0-finst,inf)

ans =

  single

   40.8451

Based on a simple perturbation analysis, the culprit dwells in the unwrapping algorithm which has a perturbation gain of 4096!.
theta = xangl;
puwrp = unwrap(theta);
% Add perturbation (numerically theta and dtheta are the same)
dtheta = theta + eps(theta)/2;
dpuwrp = unwrap(dtheta);

norm(puwrp-dpuwrp,inf)/norm(theta-dtheta,inf)

ans =

  single

        4096
```


Have you tried $f[n] = \dfrac{F_s/2}{\pi} \mathrm{atan2}\left(z[n]z^*[n-1]\right)$?  It is OK for small deviations.

Have you tried least squares phase unwrapping? Like this one https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/65565-fast-2d-phase-unwrapping

@AndyWalls: I'm not sure how this approach would improve accuracy in single precision.

I think that phase unwrapping is not the best solution for computing the instantaneous frequency. You can't avoid (approximative) differentiation, but it's more stable to directly use the signal and its derivatives instead of a phase function which may contain artifacts due to unwrapping.
The instantaneous frequency is defined as
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\phi'(t)\tag{1}$$
where $\phi(t)$ is the instantaneous phase of an analytic signal
$$w(t)=u(t)+jv(t)=r(t)e^{j\phi(t)}\tag{2}$$
Taking the derivative of $(2)$ gives
\begin{align*}
w'(t) &= r'(t)e^{j\phi(t)}+jr(t)e^{j\phi(t)}\phi'(t)\\
& = w(t)\left(\frac{r'(t)}{r(t)}+j\phi'(t)\right) \tag{3}
\end{align*}
from which it follows that
\begin{align*}
\phi'(t) &= \textrm{Im}\left\{\frac{w'(t)}{w(t)}\right\} \\
&= \textrm{Im}\left\{\frac{u'(t)+jv'(t)}{u(t)+jv(t)}\right\} \\
&= \frac{u(t)v'(t)-u'(t)v(t)}{u^2(t)+v^2(t)} \tag{4}
\end{align*}

Thanks @Matt L. for your prompt reply. This is exactly what I tried before using the unwrap approach. In single precision arithimetic, the result of this approach is worse than the unwrap approach, which motivated me to take the unwrap approach. Is there any other ways to find the instantaneous frequency from the equivalent analytic form of a signal?

@AHT: I'm surprised that your results are worse. How did you compute the derivatives? There's a paper comparing several practical ways of computing the expression $(4)$ in my answer.

@ Matt L.: I dont have access to that paper. I used both forward difference and central difference approximations which lead to similar results.
